# POST body undefined causes node.js server to shut

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, body-parser

I am sending username and password through POST to a Node.js API on /user/login route. This is the function:

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(!user) {
            res.json({success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password!'});
        } else {
            if(!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                res.json({success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password!'});
            } else {
                var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                    expiresInMinutes: 1440
                });

                res.json({success: true, token: new Buffer(token).toString('base64')});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

To get the post body variables I am using body-parser module. Whenever I send a POST request without the email, `req.body.email` returns `undefined` and mongoose finds the first user in the database (without the email validation).

This is fine because it then checks the password and returns the error message. The problem is, `bcrypt.compareSync` returns an error when `req.body.password` is `undefined` and crashes node.js with something like this:

```
throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof hash));
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
```

I can check first if the variable is undefined or not but there must be a better way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't execute any portion of the login function if the email is undefined - major security hole if the first email in the database is automatically selected. Checking that the values are defined before passing to the API functions is actually the best way to handle your problem. Try:

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('email') && req.body.hasOwnProperty('password')) {
        User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user) {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user) {
                res.json({success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password!'});
            } else {
                if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                    var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                        expiresInMinutes: 1440
                    });
                    res.json({success: true, token: new Buffer(token).toString('base64')});
                } else {
                    res.json({success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password!'});
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually doing it already using js typeof. Did not know about hasOwnProperty. Thank you.